# Any Way to Scroll to An Element in Express.js

Tags: express

I want to scroll to a particular element in my express app

rotue / loads index.html

route /#about-trigger opens index.html#about-trigger (scroll to the element in index.html)

How to Achive this

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling to a particular element happens on the *browser*, not on the *server*. It works if the browser already requests `http://server/index.html#about-trigger`.

If you don't want to assume that, the server can redirect the browser:

```js
app.get("/index.html", function(req, res) {
  if (req.query.fragment === undefined)
    res.redirect("?fragment#about-trigger");
  else
    res.sendFile("index.html");
});
```

Note the use of the `fragment` query option. Without it, the redirection would cause an endless loop, because the server does not "see" the fragment `#about-trigger` in the request (even though it can include such a fragment in the redirection response).